# DOM onmouseover not appearing

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to insert an onmouseover when creating new rows within my table however it's not appearing. Am I missing something stupid?

```
    var row = document.createElement("TR");
    row.id = i;
    row.onmouseover = hover(i);
    var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
    row.appendChild(td1);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
```

The variable 'i' is the current number in the loop. The ID of the row appears fine, but not the onmouseover.

Comment: Ids can not be numbers. Part of HTML spec.

Comment: @epascarello: browsers have always allowed numbers for IDs, and that's probably why [HTML5 allows an ID to start with and contain any character](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an anonymous function to create a closure for the value of `i`, and *make sure you're setting a function to `onmouseover`*, rather than the result of calling a function:

```
var row = document.createElement("TR");
(function (i) {
    row.onmouseover = function () { hover(i) };
})(row.id);
var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
row.appendChild(td1);
tbody.appendChild(row);
```

---

Taking a proper look at your code, it appears that you're not actually setting the `id` attribute of the TR element.  However, you might want to avoid that entirely and use `this` context inside the hover function:

```
var row = document.createElement("TR");
row.onmouseover = hover;
var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
row.appendChild(td1);
tbody.appendChild(row);
```

```
function hover() { 
    alert(this.rowIndex);  // <-- `this` refers to the row element
}
```

Comment: Ahh! I understand it now. I did this, and it created the id happily, but still not the onmouseover. I'm slightly perplexed by it.

Comment: Reason this fails is not because of the code, but the id is a number. The id needs to be valid for getElementById to use it.

Comment: @epascarello: that's not true. Read the reply I wrote to your comment on the question.

Comment: @Meekel: I noticed you're not actually setting the `id` attribute/property for the newly created element - that's why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the result of the function to the event.

Needs to be something like

```
row.onmouseover=function(){hover(this);}
```

And it is better to use this since you have the DOM object and do not have to look up anything.

```
function hover( row ){
     row.style.color = "red";
}
```

If you still what to go the i way, you need to change your id so it is valid. Ids can not start with a number.

```
var row = document.createElement("TR");
row.id = "row_i";
row.onmouseover = function(){ hover(this.id); }
var td1 = document.createElement("TD");
row.appendChild(td1);
tbody.appendChild(row);
```

Comment: +1 for a solution potentially overlooked by other answers (including mine).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try:

```
row.onmouseover = function() { hover(i); };
```

Comment: *The variable 'i' is the current number in the loop.* - so your solution won't work correctly.